# Переделка программы для использования многопоточности

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Имеется программа Windows service, написанная на C#, которая периодически получает набор данных у стороннего web-cервиса, обрабатывает их  и записывает в базу данных.
Изначально не подразумевалась последовательная загрузка массивов данных. Сначала грузится один набор, потом следующий и т.д.
Но со временем объём загружаемых данных и кол-во наборов увеличилось и возникла необходимость загружать их в параллельном режиме. Загрузка одного набора данных стала занимать более часа.
Если говорить вкратце, то требуется запуск метода одного и того же класса с различными параметрами в многопоточном режиме.
Каждый поток должен запускаться в изолированном режиме и не должен каким-либо образом влиять на одновременное выполнение других аналогичных потоков. Параллельно запускаемые потоки никак между собой не взаимодействуют. Т.е. необходимо чтобы каждый поток работал только со своими экземплярами данных и никак не мог испортить значения переменных, используемых другим потоком.

Грубо говоря есть некий класс DataMultiLoader, содержащий метод Load_and_Export

```
public class DataMultiLoader
{
                public DataMultiLoader(ServiceLogger p_svLogger)
                {
                    svLogger = p_svLogger;
                    cMTExporter = new Farelogix.MTExport.FQ_Exporter();
                }
            
                public void Load_and_Export(eProviders p_Provider, int p_nRRKey, RoutesLoadScheduler p_RScheduler)
                {   
                // здесь выполняется много работы с вызовом методов других классов, в том числе и статических
                    ...
                }
        
        }
```

Отдельная процедура LoadMultiThreading, которая вызывается по таймеру, должна запускать Load_and_Export из класса DataMultiLoader в рамках отдельного изолированного потока.

```
private void LoadMultiThreading(eBookingProviders p_Provider, int p_nRRKey) {

DataMultiLoader amdLoader = new DataMultiLoader(amdLogger);

...
Thread amdThread;
ThreadStart thStart;

thStart = delegate () { amdLoader.Load_and_Export(p_Provider, nSelectedRRKey, oRScheduler); };
amdThread = new System.Threading.Thread(thStart);
amdThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;
amdThread.IsBackground = true;  
amdThread.Start();
...
}
```

Я просмотрел теоретические материалы по данной теме и выяснил, что в многопоточных приложениях существует проблема состязания за ресурсы, когда один поток портит данные другого.

Что надо добавить в существующий код, чтобы сделать его потоко безопасным?

Использование локальных блокировок данных с конструкциями типа

```
lock(lockObj) {
// синхронизируемые операторы
}
```

является неприемлемым из-за большого объёма существующего кода. По-хорошему здесь не нужна какая-либо синхронизация изменения данных, а нужна полная изолированность, как если бы процедура Load_and_Export запускалась в рамках отдельного процесса.

Можно ли достичь нужного результата если  оформить класс DataMultiLoader следующим образом?

```
[Synchronization]
public class DataMultiLoader: ContextBoundObject
{
         ...
    public void Load_and_Export(eProviders p_Provider, int p_nRRKey, RoutesLoadScheduler p_RScheduler)
        {   
            ...
    }
}
```

Не будет ли в этом случае один поток, вызвавший Load_and_Export, ждать завершения этого же метода, вызванного ранее другим потоком из-за его полной блокировки ?

Comment: Вам проще будет запустить эту программу несколько раз с разными параметрами, т.е. воспользоваться процессами, вместо потоков. Как альтернатива - все глобальные переменные (в том числе статические) завернуть в `ThreadLocal`.

Comment: Чтобы один поток не портил данные другого, самый простой метод — чтобы не было разделяемых данных. Расскажите, что именно делает процедура, которая занимается загрузкой. В идеальном случае она должна получать все нужные для работы данные как параметры, не модифицировать глобальные данные. а возвращать результат в виде возвращаемого значения.

Comment: Вдогонку к @VladD: а допустимо ли будет класть полученные данные в буферы и ставить их в очередь, и дописать поток, который асинхронно смотрит за очередью и записывает все в БД? Тот еще велосипед, конечно...

Comment: @Dimanson: Этот велик официально называется [producer-consumer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428327/10105).

Comment: 2Roman Konoval
“Вам проще будет запустить эту программу несколько раз с разными параметрами, т.е. воспользоваться процессами, вместо потоков. “
Вы предлагаете сделать отдельный exe-модуль, в который вставить класс DataMultiLoader с процедурой загрузки и запускать его из Windows Service с параметрами, которые будут использоваться для вызова Load_and_Export ?
Как крайний вариант такое наверно подойдёт. Только при остановке сервиса нужно будет также как-то удалять все, запущенные процессы, из памяти.

Comment: 2Vlad 
Пока мне не очень понятно, что закладывается в понятие разделяемых данных.  Из предоставленного примера кода видно, что в LoadMultiThreading (который вызывается периодически по таймеру) для каждого потока создаётся НОВЫЙ экземпляр класса DataMultiLoader и затем создаётся новый поток, в котором вызывается метод Load_and_Export этого класса. В данном случае будут разделяемые данные у данных потоков или у каждый поток будет работать со своими экземплярами полей ? Тут надо ещё учитывать, что из  Load_and_Export вызываются методы другие классов, некоторые могут быть статическими.

Comment: 2Dimanson
Возможно это было бы приемлемо при построении нового приложения. Но здесь требуется доработать существующее. В таком случае потребуется его полностью переделать, что неприемлемо по трудозатратам.

Comment: Благодарю всех откликнувшихся.
Жаль, что не получил ответы на последние 2 вопроса из основного блока

Comment: `Вы предлагаете сделать отдельный exe-модуль` - да. Что касается вопроса про то, как работает Synchronization, то его лучше задать отдельно. Это простой сфокусированный вопрос, и на него, уверен, здесь дадут ответ специалисты. Я оформил это в виде отдельного вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1295814/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-net-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%82-synchronization-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%81-contextboundobject

Comment: 2Roman Konval
Спасибо за рекомендации и создание дополнительной темы. Подождём, может ещё кто-нибудь что-то дельное скажет.
Если Windows-сервис будет вызывать периодически один тот же внешний exe-модуль с различными параметрами. Могут ли в таком механизме существовать какие-либо ограничения ?

Comment: Для процессов ограничения могут быть, если они использую разделяемые ресурсы _вне процесса_, например, пишут в тот же файл или изменяют те же строки в БД.

Comment: `что закладывается в понятие разделяемых данных` - это любые данные, к которым имеют доступ два (или больше) потока. Если говорить о экземплярах, которые созданы в функции и не сохраняются в глобальных (статических) переменных и не сохраняются в объектах, к которым имеют доступ разные потоки, то они не разделяемые, ведь к ним только один поток может получить доступ.

Comment: 2Roman Konoval  Понял, спасибо.