# Как в .net работает атрибут [Synchronization] в связке с ContextBoundObject?

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность

Я прочитал документацию по:

1. [ContextBoundObject](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.contextboundobject?view=net-5.0)
2. [SynchronizationAttribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.remoting.contexts.synchronizationattribute?view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=net-5.0).
3. А также [обзорную статью](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/synchronizing-data-for-multithreading#synchronized-context) по синхронизации

но из прочитанного не понимаю, как этим пользоваться. В частности, вот тут:

> you can use the SynchronizationAttribute on any ContextBoundObject to synchronize all instance methods and fields. All objects in the same context domain share the same lock

не ясно, что значит `in the same context domain`. Как объект ассоциировать с `context domain`, откуда эти домены берутся - непонятно.

Или вот эта часть документации:

> A new object is placed into an existing context or into a new context created using the attributes included in the metadata of the type

Тут не ясно, в каком случае все таки будет создан новый контекст. Я интерпретирую эту часть документации так, что `SynchronizationAttribute` - это один из примеров тех метаданных, которые определяют правила, когда будет создан новый контекст, но какие эти правила для `[Synchronization]` не вполне понятно, документация по нему для меня туманна:

> When this attribute is applied to an object, only one thread can be executing in all contexts that share an instance of this property. This is done by contributing sinks that intercept and serialize incoming calls for the respective contexts

Что здесь значит `in all contexts that share an instance of this property`? О каком `property` идет речь в `this property`? Из этого предложения следует, что контекстов может быть много. Если это так, то как я управляю (если управляю) их созданием или как ассоциирую экземпляры (или классы?) с ними.

Пример кода:

```
[Synchronization]
public class A: ContextBoundObject
{
    public void f() {   
    }
}
```

Если я создам разные экземпляры класса `A`, будет ли у каждого свой `context domain` (и соответственно можно будет вызывать f параллельно для разных экземпляров)? Или в этом случае будет создан один `context domain` для всего класса?

Comment: [_A new object is placed into an existing context or into a new context created using the attributes included in the metadata of the type._](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.contextboundobject?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Это я тоже видел, но для меня это не проясняет картину.

Comment: "In the same context domain" в документации означает, что указанные объекты или сущности находятся в одном контексте домена. Т.о. они могут взаимодействовать друг с другом и использовать общую информацию

Comment: объект может быть ассоциирован с доменом контекста с помощью наследования от класса ContextBoundObject. домены контекста являются частью CLR и управляют жизненным циклом и контекстом выполнения для объектов. каждый домен контекста имеет свой собственный контекст выполнения, включая память, контекст управления потоками и специфическую информацию о среде

Answer (score 0):

Атрибут Synchronization в .NET работает в сочетании с ContextBoundObject, чтобы гарантировать, что все операции, выполняемые над объектом, выполняются синхронно, а это означает, что несколько потоков могут безопасно обращаться к одному и тому же объекту, не попадая в условия гонки. Это делается путем получения блокировки объекта каждый раз, когда к нему обращается поток, и снятия блокировки только тогда, когда поток завершает работу с объектом. Это гарантирует, что только один поток может получить доступ к объекту в любой момент времени и что любые изменения, сделанные одним потоком, видны всем другим потокам.

Comment: Это я все понимаю на таком общем уровне. Тут нет ответа на более конктретные вопросы, которые заданы