# Создание повторяющихся тасков для сервера

Tags: c#, клиент-сервер, tpl

Короче, пишу сервер на C# в целях попрактиковаться.

Нужно сделать чтоб сервер вытаскивал из `TcpListener` входящие подключения. Допустим есть для этого асинхронная функция, она по сути возвращает `Task` в состоянии ожидания подключения. Так вот, как правильно эту функцию зациклить?

И также, допустим я сделаю асинхронные функции для обработки подключений, там буду ждать пока в `NetworkStream` клиента не появятся данные, а потом их оттуда вытаскивать.

Получается, таски для принятия подключений и для обработки входящих запросов нужно создавать пока сервер работает.

Или вот, допустим, я хочу чтоб сервер каждому клиенту раз в n-ое время отправлял какую-нибудь служебную информацию, то-есть опять-же нужно создавать таски с определённым интервалом.

Так вот, как правильно создавать повторяющиеся таски?

И вообще правильно ли делать сетевое взаимодействие оным образом? Я ещё ничего особо не писал, просто оцениваю пути решения задачи.

Comment: Таймер чем то не подходит?

Comment: В первом, и во втором случае - нет.

Comment: Чем именно не подходит?

Comment: Новый таск для принятия и обработки подключения, должен создаваться, когда предыдущий разрешится, тоже самое с запросами.

Comment: звучит как цикл. Цикл пробовали? Вот еще есть пример в доке https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener?view=net-6.0

Comment: Ну так конечно можно, но тогда, если я правильно понимаю, у меня один поток будет занят тем, что в цикле ждёт старый и после создаёт новый таск. Правильно ли так делать?

Comment: Правильно или нет - зависит от задачи. Я вашу задачу не понимаю, ес честно.

Comment: Прилинковал решения, отвечающие на ваш вопрос. Также внимательно поизучайте шаблон проектирования Producer/Consumer, не важно где найдете его описание, можно даже сразу в нескольких источниках почитать.

Comment: @aepot за паттерном далеко ходить и не надо https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428327/179763