# Загрузка данных из файлов в память последовательно с#

Tags: c#, массивы, файлы, память, файловый-ввод-вывод

Может кто подсказать, как на с# грамотно организовать такую штуку:

Есть алгоритм, который использует большие двумерные массивы double данных последовательно. То есть сначала обрабатывает один, потом другой и тд. Результат работы по первому массиву, влияет на работу по второму массиву и тд.

Массивы выгружаются из файлов, файлы выбираются перед началом работы алгоритма.

Я хочу, чтобы **файлы загружались в программу** (*может быть сохранялись в отдельную папку, из которой программа их будет брать (чтобы по всему диску не бегать и искать)*), потом по мере работы алгоритма **загружались в память** (*сначала первый массив из файла считался, потом он удалился из памяти и загрузился второй и тд*).

У меня именно такой алгоритм, который должен последовательно без разрыва (нет промежуточного результата как бы) сначала использовать один массив данных, потом другой. То есть, есть одно поле класса, в один момент работы алгоритма оно должно хранить один массив, в другой строго определенный момент другой массив. Пока что я сделала так - загружаю все массивы в очередь, потом по мере работы алгоритма удаляю использованный массив из очереди. Но это может использовать много памяти, нужно минимизировать используемую память.

Может кто скинет ссылку на такую информацию, потому что я даже не могу сообразить как этот процесс обозвать, чтобы найти в интернете)

Comment: Что-то непонятно в чём вопрос. Просто берёте и делаете это всё. Если делать загрузку в отдельном методе, то вся память, которая использовалась этим методом, будет освобождена по выходе из него. Если физически память не будет освобождаться, а вам это прям надо - можно принудительно пнуть `GC`. Хотя обычно и без этого всё хорошо. Непонятен только момент с влиянием - у вас получается какой-то результат, который вы передаёте дальше? Ну, возвращайте его из функции загрузки и потом опять в неё передавайте, когда следующий файл будете обрабатывать. Либо в переменных класса храните это.

Comment: у меня именно такой алгоритм, который должен последовательно без разрыва (нет промежуточного результата как бы) сначала использовать один массив данных, потом другой.
То есть, есть одно поле класса, в один момент работы алгоритма оно должно хранить один массив, в другой строго определенный момент другой массив. Разрывать ход алгоритма нельзя (там цикл).
Пока что я сделала так - загружаю все массивы в очередь, потом по мере работы алгоритма удаляю использованный массив из очереди

Comment: Ну загружайте их по одному. Что мешает делать загрузку в нужный момент, а не заранее?

Comment: Из теоретического можете сюда посмотреть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428327/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-producer-consumer-pattern Хотя тут больше про многопоточный вариант, но может это чем-то поможет осознать.

Comment: @CrazyElf `можно принудительно пнуть GC` - вредный совет.

Comment: @aepot В чём проблема c использование GC.Collect(). Я, конечно, его не использую, но стало интересно - в чём проблема вызывать его самостоятельно. Или стоит задать отдельным вопросом это? Я понимаю, что в конце контекста весь мусор будет собран и так, но почему не стоит вообще использовать - вопрос

Comment: Например, при большом количестве объектов было-бы, наверное, оправдано использование, во время слишком большого метода

Comment: @Frehzy это наносит ущерб производительности, а эффекта зачастую не дает. То есть применять данный метод можно тогда и только тогда, когда тесты показывают от этого положительный эффект. Но я таких случаев ни разу не встречал. Можете задать конечно вопрос, но вроде на него здесь уже отвечали, не припомню только где именно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужна реализация шаблона проектирования Producer/Consumer с ограничением буфера. Под эту задачу легко подходит `Channel`.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Channel<int> channel = Channel.CreateBounded<int>(2);
    Task consumerTask = ConsumeAsync(channel.Reader);
    Task producerTask = ProduceAsync(channel.Writer);
    await Task.WhenAll(producerTask, consumerTask);
}

static async Task ProduceAsync(ChannelWriter<int> writer)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        await writer.WriteAsync(i);
        Console.WriteLine($"> {i}");
    }
    writer.Complete();
}

static async Task ConsumeAsync(ChannelReader<int> reader)
{
    await foreach (int number in reader.ReadAllAsync())
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"< {number}");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

Здесь я создаю канал передачи данных на буфер размером в 2 ячейки, то есть при попытке положить третий элемент в канал происходит ожидание до тех пор, пока не освободится место в буфере.

Таким образм можно сгладить задержки при чтении данных и отдаче в обработку.

Вывод в консоль, добавлю комментов

```
> 1
< 1 // здесь первый элемент извлекается сразу, но может и позже, чем появится второй элемент
> 2
> 3 // 2 элемента в буфере, будет ждать, пока не будет извлечен очередной элемент
< 2 // вот он извлекается
> 4 // и сразу же кладется следующий
< 3
> 5
< 4
> 6
< 5
> 7
< 6
> 8
< 7
> 9
< 8
> 10 // последний отправлен в обработку, далее только освобождение буфера
< 9
< 10
```

То есть регулируя размер буфера, вы сможете регулировать потребление памяти приложением. И да, как вы уже догадались, чтение и запись элементов - две параллельно выполняемых операции.

Почитать подробнее про каналы можно [здесь](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/).

Comment: спасибо, буду пробовать)